# Transaction rollback inconsistent

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

We have a transaction that has a fair number of updates and inserts that run inside it as sent by our server-side code.  We've run into an issue where all work in the transaction up to a given point is rolled back, and then later updates/inserts are run and end up being committed when the transaction is closed.

We narrowed it down to a bit of code where it would always happen and pulled that code out.  Then the same behavior started happening elsewhere in the transaction.  Nothing in our code is telling the transaction to roll back, and we haven't changed our code on our prod servers for quite a while before it started happening.

We finally restarted our prod db server and the problem went away, for a little while.  Then it started happening again, and happened consistently after that.

We're on SQL Server 2016 and our web server is running ColdFusion 11 hotfix 18.  Queries are being issued via `<cfquery>` inside a `<cftransaction>`.

Has anyone run into anything like this or have any way to diagnose the issue?

Update w/ more info:  Apparently SQL Server was processing hardly any updates.  We finally discovered that a log file was out of space.  This usually will produce notifications/errors that this has happened, but this time it didn't for some reason.  I realize this question is probably not the very highest quality, but in hopes that anyone who may run into this will find this and gain some benefit, I'm leaving it here.

Comment: Its going to be very hard to anyone to help without specifics. You also might want to try on the dba stackexchange site. However the first thing I would do is familiarise yourself with XACT_ABORT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a way to migrate the question to that site rather than close and re-ask over there?

Comment: Not that I know of - you can leave it open here anyway. You might get closed on either site for being a bit too board.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that is causing issues? Is this a nested `cftransaction`? Is there other code being run between your `cfquery`s? Does your `cftransaction` specify the isolation level?

Comment: Was the log space the cause or just a symptom of all of the activity?

Comment: The cause.  Once there was more space the issue stopped.  It resumed when it ran out of space again (apparently restarting the db server freed up just enough space to let it run for a little while before it filled up again).